# Resolving an issue creating a file within a shared folder within a virtual machine

Tags: text, time, touch, settings

Set up a VM and created a shared folder and within this folder wanted to create a file using the touch command and got this

touch: setting times of 'text.txt': No such file or directory

Can anyone help?

Expecting it to run smoothly